# Understanding Mini-Kanren's Execution Model

Tags: clojure, scheme, logic, minikanren

Chapter 5 of SICP explains the scheme meta circular evaluator interns of a register machine.

Is there anything that provides a similar type of Mini-Kanren in terms of Scheme primitives?

I know that there is a Thesis written on Mini-Kanren (however, I only care about building a mental model; not all the gory optimizations details). I also know that there is the reasoned-schemer -- however, I'm not looking for a bunch of examples -- I just want to understand Mini-kanren in its' very very basic form, much like how one can understand scheme by understanding: eval, apply, if, set!, env

Thanks!

Comment: [here is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10848902/849891) an 18-lines Haskell implementation of The Reasoned Schemer (sans unification and logical variables).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think reading *The Reasoned Schemer* is actually the right way to learn the basics. You could also try watching Dan Friedman and William Byrd's [miniKanren talk](http://blip.tv/clojure/dan-friedman-and-william-byrd-minikanren-5936333) from Clojure Conj.

Since miniKanren only has [seven forms](http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/dfriedman/miniKanren.plt/1/1/doc.txt) total, understanding the basic forms is really just understanding the whole thing. The implementation is only about [a page](http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/dfriedman/miniKanren.plt/1/1/minikanren.ss) of macros, so you could try to understand that. You could also try reading the introductory parts of William Byrd's [PhD thesis](https://scholarworks.iu.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/2022/8777/Byrd_indiana_0093A_10344.pdf?sequence=1).

Comment: The link to the talk is down, unfortunately.

Comment: Seems so. Links to other miniKanren talks are available here: http://minikanren.org/

Answer (score 3):

In the book [The Reasoned Schemer](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=10663) there's an implementation of a very simple logic system on top of Scheme. It's self-contained, the only thing needed for understanding it is the book itself, which - in the style of the other books in the series, is extremely easy to follow.