# conda, condi, conde, condu

Tags: clojure, scheme, clojure-core.logic, minikanren, reasoned-schemer

I'm reading [the Reasoned Schemer](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=10663).

I have some intuition about how `conde` works.

However, I can't find a formal definition of what `conde`/`conda`/`condu`/`condi` do.

I'm aware of https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~webyrd/ but that seems to have examples rather than definitions.

Is there a formal definition of `conde`, `conda`, `condi`, `condu` somewhere?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In Prolog's terms,

- **`condA`** is *"soft cut"* a.k.a. **`*->`**, where `A *-> B ; C` is like `(A, B ; not(A), C)`, only *better* ; whereas
- **`condU`** is *"committed choice"*, a combination of `once` and a soft cut so that `(once(A) *-> B ; false)` expresses `(A, !, B)` (with the *cut* inside):

```ml
condA:     A        *->  B  ;  C        %  soft cut,
                                        %     (A ,    B ; not(A) , C)
condU:     once(A)  *->  B  ;  C        %  committed choice,
                                        %     (A , !, B ; not(A) , C)
```

(with **`;`** meaning *"or"* and **`,`** meaning *"and"*, i.e. *disjunction* and *conjunction* of goals, respectively).

In **`condA`**, if the goal `A` succeeds, all the solutions are passed through to the first clause `B` and no alternative clauses `C` are tried.

In **`condU`**, `once/1` allows its argument goal to succeed only once (keeps only one solution, if any).

**`condE`** is a simple disjunction of conjunctions, and **`condI`** is a disjunction which *alternates* between the solutions of its constituents, *interleaving* the streams thereof.

---

Here's an attempt at faithfully translating the book's code, w/out the logical variables and unification, into 18 lines of Haskell which is mostly a lazy Lisp *with syntax*.<sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup> See if this clarifies things:

- Sequential stream combination ("**`mplus`**" of the book):

```hs
    (1)   []     ++: ys  =  ys
    (2)   (x:xs) ++: ys  =  x : (xs ++: ys)
```

- Alternating stream combination ("**`mplusI`**"):

  ```hs
    (3)   []     ++/ ys  =  ys
    (4)   (x:xs) ++/ ys  =  x : (ys ++/ xs)
  ```
- Sequential feed ("**`bind`**"):

  ```hs
    (5)   []     >>: g  =  []
    (6)   (x:xs) >>: g  =  g x ++: (xs >>: g)
  ```
- Alternating feed ("**`bindI`**"):

  ```hs
    (7)   []     >>/ g  =  []
    (8)   (x:xs) >>/ g  =  g x ++/ (xs >>/ g)
  ```
- "`OR`" *goal* combination ("**`condE`**"):

  ```hs
    (9)   (f ||: g) x  =  f x ++: g x
  ```
- "Alternating `OR`" goal combination ("**`condI`**"):

  ```hs
    (10)  (f ||/ g) x  =  f x ++/ g x
  ```
- "`AND`" goal combination ("**`all`**"):

  ```hs
    (11)  (f &&: g) x  =  f x >>: g
  ```
- "Alternating `AND`" goal combination ("**`allI`**" of the book):

  ```hs
    (12)  (f &&/ g) x  =  f x >>/ g
  ```
- Special goals `true` and `false` (or "success" and "failure"):

  ```hs
    (13)  true  x  =  [x]  -- a sigleton list with the same solution repackaged
    (14)  false x  =  []   -- an empty list, meaning the solution is rejected
  ```

  And why are they called `true` and `false`? Because for any goal `g`, we have e.g.

  ```hs
    (g &&: true) x  =  g x >>: true  =  g x >>: (\ x -> [x] )  =  g x
    (false &&: g) x  =  false x >>: g  =  [] >>: g  =  []  =  false x
    -- ... etc.
  ```

*Goals* produce streams (possibly empty) of (possibly updated) solutions, given a (possibly partial) solution to a problem.

Re-write rules for **`all`** are:

```hs
(all)      =  true
(all  g1)  =  g1
(all  g1 g2 g3 ...)  =  (\x -> g1 x >>: (all g2 g3 ...))
                     =  g1 &&: (g2 &&: (g3 &&: ... ))
(allI g1 g2 g3 ...)  =  (\x -> g1 x >>/ (allI g2 g3 ...))
                     =  g1 &&/ (g2 &&/ (g3 &&/ ... ))
```

Re-write rules for **`condX`** are:

```hs
(condX)  =  false
(condX (else g1 g2 ...))  =  (all g1 g2 ...)  =  g1 &&: (g2 &&: (...))
(condX (g1 g2 ...))       =  (all g1 g2 ...)  =  g1 &&: (g2 &&: (...))
(condX (g1 g2 ...) (h1 h2 ...) ...)  =  (ifX g1 (all g2 ...) 
                                          (ifX h1 (all h2 ...) (...) ))
```

To arrive at the final **`condE`** and **`condI`**'s translation, there's no need to implement the book's **`ifE`** and **`ifI`**, since they reduce further to simple operator combinations, with all the operators considered to be *right-associative*:

```hs
(condE (g1 g2 ...) (h1 h2 ...) ...)  =
     (g1 &&: g2 &&: ... )  ||:  (h1 &&: h2 &&: ...)  ||:  ...
(condI (g1 g2 ...) (h1 h2 ...) ...)  =
     (g1 &&: g2 &&: ... )  ||/  (h1 &&: h2 &&: ...)  ||/  ...
```

So there's no need for any special "syntax" in Haskell, plain binary infix operators suffice. Any combination can be used anywhere, with `&&/` instead of `&&:` as needed. But on the other hand **`condI`** could also be implemented as a function to accept a collection (list, tree etc.) of goals to be fulfilled, that would use some smart strategy to pick of them one most likely or most needed etc, and not just simple binary alternation as in `||/` operator (or **`ifI`** of the book).

Next, the book's **`condA`** can be modeled by *two* new operators, `~~>` and `||~`, working together. We can use them in a natural way as in e.g.

```hs
g1 ~~> g2 &&: ...  ||~  h1 ~~> h2 &&: ...  ||~  ...  ||~  gelse
```

which can intuitively be read as "`IF g1 THEN g2 AND ... OR-ELSE IF h1 THEN ... OR-ELSE gelse`":

- "`IF-THEN`" goal combination is to produce a *"try"* goal which must be called with a failure-continuation goal:

  ```hs
    (15)  (g ~~> h) f x  =  case g x of [] -> f x  ;  ys -> ys >>: h
  ```
- "`OR-ELSE`" goal combination of a *try* goal and a simple goal simply calls its *try* goal with a second, on-failure goal, so it's nothing more than a convenience syntax for automatic grouping of operands:

  ```hs
    (16)  (g ||~ f) x  =  g f x
  ```

With the "`OR-ELSE`" `||~` operator given less binding power than the "`IF-THEN`" `~~>` operator and made right-associative too, and `~~>` operator having still less binding power than `&&:` and the like, sensible grouping of the above example is automatically produced as

```hs
(g1 ~~> (g2 &&: ...))  ||~  ( (h1 ~~> (h2 &&: ...))  ||~  (...  ||~  gelse ...) )
```

Last goal in an `||~` chain must thus be a simple goal. That's no limitation really, since last clause of **`condA`** form is equivalent anyway to simple "`AND`"-combination of its goals (or simple `false` can be used just as well).

That's all. We can even have more types of *try* goals, represented by different kinds of "`IF`" operators, if we want:

- use alternating feed in a successful clause (to model what could've been called **`condAI`**, if there were one in the book):

  ```hs
    (17)  (g ~~>/ h) f x  =  case g x of [] -> f x  ;  ys -> ys >>/ h
  ```
- use the successful solution stream only *once* to produce the *cut* effect, to model **`condU`**:

  ```hs
    (18)  (g ~~>! h) f x  =  case g x of [] -> f x  ;  (y:_) -> h y
  ```

So that, finally, the re-write rules for **`condA`** and **`condU`** of the book are simply:

```hs
(condA (g1 g2 ...) (h1 h2 ...) ...)  = 
      g1 ~~> g2 &&: ...  ||~  h1 ~~> h2 &&: ...  ||~  ... 

(condU (g1 g2 ...) (h1 h2 ...) ...)  = 
      g1 ~~>! g2 &&: ...  ||~  h1 ~~>! h2 &&: ...  ||~  ...
```

---

<sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup> which is:

- simple *juxtaposition* is *curried function application*,
      `f a b c  =~=  (((f a) b) c)  =~=  f(a, b, c)`
- `(\ a -> b )` is *lambda function,* `(lambda (a) b)`
- `foo x = y` is shorthand for `foo = (\ x -> y )`
- `a @@ b = y` is shorthand for `(@@) a b = y`, definition of an infix operator `@@`
- parentheses `(` `)` are just for grouping
- `[]` is the empty list, *and*
- `:` means *cons* -- both as a constructor ( *lazy*, as the whole language is *lazy*, i.e. *call by need* ), on the *right* of `=` in definitions; and as a destructuring pattern, on the *left* (or in pattern-matching `case` expressions).

Comment: 5 uparrows on stack overflow is not worthy of this response. I hope you turn this into a blog post or something.

Comment: As a followup: is COND? == OR? and ALL? == AND? ?

Comment: @user1383359 more or less. CONDe is Prolog's OR (disjunction), and ALL - Prolog's AND (conjunction). CONDi, ALLi, are a variation on sub-goals solutions merging order, trying to build-in the prevention of non-productive behaviour into the system in advance.

Answer (score 16):

The Reasoned Schemer covers **conda** (soft cut) and **condu** (committed choice). You'll also find explanations of their behavior in William Byrd's excellent [dissertation on miniKanren](https://scholarworks.iu.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/2022/8777/Byrd_indiana_0093A_10344.pdf?sequence=1). You've tagged this post as being about core.logic. To be clear core.logic is based on a more recent version of miniKanren than the one presented in The Reasoned Schemer. miniKanren is always interleaves disjunctive goals - **condi** and the interleaving variants no longer exist. **conde** *is* **condi** now.

Comment: FWIW to people reading today, the second edition of The Reasoned Schemer now uses an interleaving conde by default.

Answer (score 4):

By Example, using core.logic:

conde will run every group, succeed if at least one group succeeds, and **return all results from all successful groups.**

```
user>  (run* [w q]
                (conde [u#]
                       [(or* [(== w 1) (== w 2)])
                        (== q :first)]
                       [(== q :second)]))
([_0 :second] [1 :first] [2 :first])
```

conda and condu: both will stop after the first successful group(top to bottom)

conda **returns all results from only the first successful group.**

```
user> (run* [w q]
                (conda [u#]
                       [(or* [(== w 1) (== w 2)])
                        (== q :first)]
                       [(== q :second)]))
([1 :first] [2 :first])
```

condu **returns only one result from only the first successful group.**

```
user> (run* [w q]
                (condu [u#]
                       [(or* [(== w 1) (== w 2)])
                        (== q :first)]
                       [(== q :second)]))
([1 :first])
```

No idea what condi does though.

Comment: Not a formal definition but it might help

Comment: as dnolen writes in his answer here, conde of core.logic is condi of the book. conde of the book processes its subgoals in order, sequentially. if first successive subgoal produced an _infinite_ stream of answers, no other successful subgoals' solutions would show up in the combined solutions stream. condi of the book remedied that by interleaving the streams.

Comment: awesome! now i know. didnt catch the stream/interleaving part back when.
revisiting core.logic src as of now

Answer (score 1):

According to the ISO Prolog core standard control structures such as (,)/2, (;)/2 and (->)/2 are cut transparent. (*->)/2 is not found in the ISO Prolog core standard, but usually Prolog systems implement it also cut transparent.

This means one cannot translate:

```
once(A) *-> B;C
```

Into `A, !, B; C`. Because the later might be embedded in other control structures, and if there are disjunctions among them, these choice points would be also cut away. What on the other hand seems reasonable, to view it as `A -> B; C`,

known simply as ISO Prolog core standard **if-then-else**. The thus defined behaviour of the cut, is for example useful to break out of repeat loops, without throwing an exception. The usual programming pattern is more difficult to archive with if-then-else.

Comment: you probably meant some goal like `(X=1;X=2),(Y=1,!,Z=1 ; Z=2)` producing just one result, whereas both `(X=1;X=2),(Y=1 -> Z=1 ; Z=2)` and `(X=1;X=2),(once(Y=1) *-> Z=1 ; Z=2)` producing two? but the book doesn't have `!` or `->` in the first place. all it has is these stream manipulations.

Comment: thanks for the link. my answer is not about the Prolog translation though. the Haskell code in it is a translation of the Scheme code from the *book*. and since *there's no cut* in the book's language, I think the two Prolog snippets are also a correct translation of `conda` and `condu` into Prolog (even though it wasn't at all the goal of the answer; just an illustration). cascading the `*->` shouldn't be a problem, right? even in Prolog this is about the parenthesization issues, which can always be fixed / made explicit by defining auxiliary predicates instead, to prevent the cut leakage.

Comment: (I assume very few of the book readers / minikanren users / know Prolog, relatively speaking ... even Haskell was an edgy choice back then, but it *has* become more popular with the years, and the code is so simple, it's basically a pseudocode).