# If satisfiable, cut before, otherwise fail

Tags: prolog

Please see this code snipped:

```
...,
findall(X, predicate(Input1, X), XS),
XS \== [],
!,
member(X, XS),
...
```

That will find all solutions for `predicate(_, X)` in `XS`, cut, then "iterate" over the X in XS.

Is it possible to replace `findall/3` in here? Most likely I won't be interested in *all* solutions for X. I need to know if it is satisfiable for Input1, and if so, continue with its solutions.

---

Please notice that this is, of course, not what I am looking for:

```
predicate(Input1, X),     % Uses other values for Input1
```

Neither is this:

```
!, predicate(Input1, X),  % I could need another value for Input1
```

And esp. not this:

```
predicate(Input1, X), !,  % I want further solutions for X
```

Comment: *Why* isn't `predicate(Input1,X)` what you're looking for? Usually with Prolog if you don't want all the answers you simply don't generate them all in a list. If you want a subset of the answers, you make a more selective predicate and then use that from `findall/3` et. al. Why aren't these approaches acceptable for you?

Comment: @DanielLyons in my actual code `predicate(...)` is `call(Fun, ...)`, Fun comes from `member(Fun, (foo, bar, baz, qux))`. If `bar(Input1, X)` has a solution, then I do not care for `bar(Input1, X)` or `qux(Input1, X)`. With findall my code works well, but I do not think that it is the best™ implementation for my problem. :-)

Comment: I would expect `once(predicate(...))` would do what you want, or else extracting the part with the difficulties to its own predicate and then using `once` around that. But I am having trouble understanding your problem in the abstract.

Comment: do you mean that you need all the solutions for the first `Input1` value that succeeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
predicate(Input1,X), !, (Y=X ; predicate(Input1,Y), Y \= X).
```

I think that's very similar (not to say, exactly the same as) the soft cut, `predicate(Input1,X) *-> ...`. It is also [`CONDa` from the "Reasoned Schemer" book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843563/conda-condi-conde-condu/10848902#10848902). I think.

Actually, this is not exactly the same as what you wanted. The following is closer, I think:

```
predicate(Input1,_), !, predicate(Input1,X).
```

Comment: Thank you! I really like the last line.

Comment: Yeah, as usual in Prolog, just writing down what you mean solves it. (still it runs it twice for the first successful value...)