# How to use replicateM solving the eight queens problem?

Tags: haskell, monads, type-mismatch, n-queens, replicate

I just started learning to code Haskell so apologies if this is a stupid question. I am trying to redo the eight queens problem by making use of the `[]` monad. Here is the code,

```
import Control.Monad

addqueen :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
addqueen xs = [ x:xs | x <- [1,2..8], 
    not $ x `elem` xs 
        || (any (\ (index,q) -> abs (x-q) == index) $ zip [1..] xs) ]
```

When I try

```
[[]] >>= replicateM 8 addqueen
```

it does not work but yields the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `t0 -> t1' with actual type `[[a0]]'
The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
but its type `[[a0]]' has none
In the expression: [[]] >>= replicateM 8 $ addqueen
In an equation for `it': it = [[]] >>= replicateM 8 $ addqueen
```

So how do I achieve what I want to do here?

Comment: It is not really clear what you expect `[[]]>>= replicateM 8 addqueen` to do. Note that `[[]] >>= f` equals `f []`.

Comment: I can get the result if I do "[[]]>>=addqueen >>=addqueen >>=addqueen >>=addqueen >>=addqueen >>=addqueen >>=addqueen >>=addqueen" but that is really tedious. I am looking for a "syntax sugar" thing to simplify the call.

Comment: That looks like `iterate (>>= addqueen) [[]] !! 8` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: `foldl (>>=) [[]] $ replicate 8 addqueen`

Answer (score 3):

`replicateM` is the wrong choice here:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> :t replicateM
replicateM :: (Monad m) => Int -> m a -> m [a]

Prelude Control.Monad> :t addqueen
addqueen :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
```

this means that *in* the expression `replicateM 8 addqueen`, the type of `addqueen` is matched up with `m a`, giving `m a ~ ([Int] -> [[Int]])`, i.e. `m ~ ((->) [Int])` and `a ~ [[Int]]`. And thus the type of `replicateM 8 addqueen` is `m [a] ~ ([Int] -> [[[Int]]])`. This is *not* what you intended.

(if you get a type error *"No instance for `(Monad ((->) [Int]))`"*, try loading e.g. `Control.Applicative` first, to bring in the definition for `instance Monad ((->) r)`. This will happen if you're using an older version of GHC).

Try this, instead:

```
Prelude> :m +Control.Monad

Prelude Control.Monad> :t (>=>)
(>=>) :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c

Prelude Control.Monad> :t foldl1 (>=>) $ replicate 8 addqueen
foldl1 (>=>) $ replicate 8 addqueen :: [Int] -> [[Int]]

Prelude Control.Monad> :t [[]] >>= ( foldl1 (>=>) $ replicate 8 addqueen )
[[]] >>= ( foldl1 (>=>) $ replicate 8 addqueen ) :: [[Int]]
```

---

***update:*** the expression `g = foldl1 (>=>) $ replicate 8 addqueen` has a meaning on its own. In Prolog terms it is [a *"goal"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10848902/849891) of adding 8 queens to an initial solution. We *use* `g` by feeding it an initially empty solution, `[ [] ] >>= g`.

( This uses a slightly *above-basic-level* operator "fish"<sup>1</sup> i.e. [left-to-right Kleisli composition operator `>=>`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-), defined so that

```
(m >>= a) >>= b  ===  m >>= (a >=> b)
```

i.e. `>=>` is a composition operator for monadic functions. )

The expression given to you [in the comments by Sassa NF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988569/how-to-use-replicatem/18990552#comment28056173_18988569), `foldl (>>=) [[]] $ replicate 8 addqueen`, uses the basic [monadic bind operator `>>=`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad), but only works as a whole.

<sup>1</sup> http://haskellrescue.blogspot.com/2011/03/cooking-delicious-fish.html

Answer (score 0):

You miss spaces

```
addqueen xs = [x:xs|x<-[1,2..8], not $ x `elem` xs 
    || (any (\(index,q) -> abs (x-q) ==index) $ zip [1..] xs)]
```

Second, do not use several infix function together

```
--this code is invalid:
[[]] >>= replicateM 8 $ addqueen -- read as [[]] >>= (replicateM 8 $) addqueen
```

The reason is:  `infixl 1 >>=` and `infixr 0 $`

Third, if you use GHCi, write signature for "empty" data.

```
>([[]] :: [[Int]])>>= replicateM 8 addqueen
```

**Your code is valid**

```
> [[]]>>= replicateM 8 addqueen
[[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]],[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]],[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]],[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]],[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]],[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]],[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]],[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8]]]
```

Comment: I still cannot make it work. Here is what I get: No instance for (Monad ((->) [Int]))
      arising from a use of `replicateM'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Monad ((->) [Int]))
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `replicateM 8 addqueen'
    In the expression: ([[]] :: [[Int]]) >>= replicateM 8 addqueen
    In an equation for `it':
        it = ([[]] :: [[Int]]) >>= replicateM 8 addqueen

Comment: `replicateM 3 (1+) $ 4` ==> `[5,5,5]`. Not `[5,6,7]`.

Comment: @user2812201 right now you're missing `instance Monad ((->) r)`. But it's a good thing. Try `Prelude> :m +Control.Applicative` ; the code will work but it will not do what you want, but something else instead.

Comment: `[[]] >>= replicateM 8 $ addqueen` is actually read as `([[]] >>= replicateM 8) $ addqueen` which of course does not make much sense at all.