# Real examples using 3-arg infix operators in Haskell? (Like $||.)

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, coding-style, infix-operator

I've found [a bunch of operators like `$||`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.0.6/docs/src/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#%24|) in `parallel` package:

```
-- Strategic function application

{-
These are very handy when writing pipeline parallelism asa sequence of
@$@, @$|@ and @$||@'s. There is no need of naming intermediate values
in this case. The separation of algorithm from strategy is achieved by
allowing strategies only as second arguments to @$|@ and @$||@.
-}

-- | Sequential function application. The argument is evaluated using
--   the given strategy before it is given to the function.
($|) :: (a -> b) -> Strategy a -> a -> b
f $| s  = \ x -> let z = x `using` s in z `pseq` f z

-- | Parallel function application. The argument is evaluated using
-- the given strategy, in parallel with the function application.
($||) :: (a -> b) -> Strategy a -> a -> b
f $|| s = \ x -> let z = x `using` s in z `par` f z
```

But they take 3 arguments. I've seen no examples using these operators, so I need to come up with a good style for writing them.

Is the usual style for them like:

```
f $|| strategy $ expr
```

?

Comment: I use them only to combine predicates in point-free style like this: ``p .&&. q = \x -> p x && q x`` and then write my filters in a readable way ``filter (even .&&. (<10))``. I have never seen them used anywhere else, but then I also haven't seen that much Haskell code.

Comment: The comment "These are very handy when writing pipeline parallelism asa sequence of @$@, @$|@ and @$||@'s" seems to agree with your proposed style.

Comment: @chi Yes, but having a second `$` (as in my example) is a bit surprizing for a reader who expects to see some form of function application. The reader must learn that now function application can be written not with a single `$`, but with `$|| strategy` inserted in the middle. So, I thought perhaps, there was another clear way to write this down.

Comment: You can always parenthesise them: ``(f $|| strategy) expr``.

Comment: you can introduce an additional operator, equivalent to that `$`, which would "read" better, in the context (e.g. `f ~~> h ||~ g == (f ~~> h) g` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843563/conda-condi-conde-condu/10848902#10848902)). Give it the appropriately low precedence, maybe 1.

Answer (score 8):

## Precedence and `$`

So Haskell has a very regular syntax. At the highest priority is parentheses; then comes applying a function to its argument. Function application is left-associative, or, as I prefer to call it, **greedy nom**: meaning that a function "eats up" the very first thing that it sees after it as its argument. So, if you write `f g h` this becomes `(f g) h`: `f` eats `g` first, and the return value eats `h` afterward. Often, especially when you're defining a function, you want to write something like `f (Constructor parameter1 parameter2) = ...` where you really need the explicit parentheses so that you're not accidentally writing `((f Constructor) parameter1) parameter2`.

After parentheses and applications, we have operators: these which have a whole hierarchy of priorities and associativities given by the "infix directives". The lowest-priority operator is defined as:

```
f $ g = f g
infixr 0 $
```

This operator is a totally normal operator which seemingly does nothing at all: more precisely it applies the function on its left to the argument on its right. It is low-priority right-associative, so it is "lazy nom" (the function before the `$` is applied to everything after that `$`). There is an interesting syntax dispute over whether `f . g . h $ i` is more or less correct than `f $ g $ h $ i`, which does the same thing in a different way.

Remember that `$` is actually just an ordinary operator/function. For example you can do things like this:

```
Prelude> let factorial n = product [1..n]
Prelude> map ($ 3) [(5 +), (3 *), (3 +) . factorial . (2 *)]
[8,9,723]
```

Here we are creating a function `($ 3)` which takes a function as its argument, applying it to 3. We map the resulting function over several other functions. We could also write this as `zipWith ($) functions (repeat 3)` if you really wanted, passing `($)` as the combining function that zipWith will use to zip two lists together. They're the same thing, and they're both fun tricks. You might even someday want to `map (flip ($))` over a list of values, to get a list of values in the form of functions. It's an isomorphism; you can get the values back with `id = map ($ id) . map (flip ($))`, but maybe that format will be more convenient for you someday.

Lower priority than this are special forms like `if`, `let`, `case`, `do`, `where`, and `\`. In general Haskell requires that these cannot appear immediately after a value or `)`, but may appear after a `(` or an operator. So if you want to write `f \x -> 3 + 2 * x` Haskell will complain until you make this into one of the following:

```
f ((3 +) . (2 *)) -- no special forms
f (\x -> 3 + 2 * x) -- parenthesize the sub-expression
f $ \x -> 3 + 2 * x -- use $ to make the syntax "work" effortlessly.
```

Similarly you might see things like:

```
main = complicatedProcessingStep . preprocessing $ do
    input <- io_input
    ...
```

where the `$` is being used to avoid putting parentheses around the `do` so that you don't have to dangle a `)` token somewhere in the whitespace.

## Functions have one argument

One huge way that Haskell differs from other languages is that *every function has exactly one argument*. This is probably going to confuse you at first: aren't operators functions of two arguments, and what about `\a b c -> ...`, doesn't it have three?

The answer is no: `\a b c -> ...` is syntactic sugar for `\a -> \b -> \c -> ...` (this is not to mention the fact that you can pattern match on those arguments, too, so secretly `\a -> ...` is syntactic sugar for `\random_token -> case random_token of a -> ...`). Each function has one argument, but some functions return a function. In Haskell we *can* do what other languages do, and accept a tuple; `\(a, b) -> a + b` works fine, and is equivalent to `uncurry (+)`. We just usually don't do that -- we usually pass `\a b -> a + b`.

You can make an operator out of any function which returns a function. The resulting operator takes its left-hand-side as an argument for the first function and its right-hand-side for an argument to the second. The canonical way to do this is with backticks:

```
13 `mod` 7 == mod 13 7
```

but if the types are not polymorphic, or if you write an explicit type signature or disable the "monomorphism restriction", you can also write things like `(%%%) = mod`.

## Three-argument operators.

So there's your answer about "three-argument operators": it returns a function which can then be applied to other values. When you write:

```
a x $|| b y $ c z
```

because of the above rules this parses as:

```
($) (($||) (a x) (b y)) (c z)
```

which by the definition of `($)` becomes:

```
($||) (a x) (b y) (c z)
```

Just using the operator on the sub-expression, `ax $|| b y`, produces a function, which could either be applied using parentheses, as in `(a x $|| b y) (c z)`, or with the `$` operator which applies its left-hand side to its right-hand-side.