# Randomizing priority in Prolog predicates

Tags: prolog

One of the main differences between Prolog and first order logic is in the strict rule for the priority of the right parts in predicate. I would like to know if there any way to randomize this priority without renouncing at the normal backtracking behaviour.
In particular I'm working with SWI-Prolog so it would be good also a solution that works only with that interpreter.

Comment: What is the point of this? Anyway, no, there is no built-in facility for that.

Comment: Can you give a simple example? What do you mean by "priority"? Do you mean the order?

Comment: Simply the fact that left parts are executed in the order in which they compare in the program: if one fail the interpreter backtracks to another predicate.

Comment: I'm not sure what "left parts" are or what you mean by "they compare". I think it would be a better question if you described a use case of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @lurker I suspect it's about the order of goal selection, i.e. left-to-right. randomizing could maybe simulate a *parallel* Prolog. Kind of like [guarded command language by Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guarded_Command_Language), where a guard is chosen nondeterministically from among the matching guards (in the [`do`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guarded_Command_Language#Semantics_4) construct).

Comment: [tag:minikanren] is advertised to have "fair scheduling", which probably  means that the results of all goals in a disjunction are mixed / interleaved, instead of having all the results of the first (left-most) goal processed before any of the results from the other goals, as in the regular, sequential Prolog (like SWI is an implementation of). (see  `++/` and `||/` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843563/conda-condi-conde-condu/10848902#10848902)). Changing order of goals in a conjunction is more subtle, can change the overall meaning if goals are non-pure.

Comment: @lurker also, "priority" may refer to "prioritized choice" of simple linear lists, where we always pick the leftmost element (`[H|T]` --> `H-T`). But we could pick one randomly, as in math with set expressions where order of choice is (presumably) unspecified: `{ x | x <- {1..4}, even x}` could  result in `{4,2}` as well.

Comment: @WillNess I "suspect" some interpretations, too, and think the terminology being used here "may" refer to certain things. But I was hoping the OP would explain their question more clearly with examples rather than rely on my own speculations.

Answer (score 3):

Although there is no built-in way to use randomness as a search strategy in the Prolog theorem prover, there are native functions there to generate random numbers which could then be used (in a roundabout way) to randomize which instance of a predicate is chosen for consideration next.

To elaborate, you might include with each instance of a predicate `path/n` two additional tests which represent the range within 0 and 1 that predicate holds.  This range `(Lo, Hi)` should be chosen such that Hi - Lo = 1 / k, where k is the total number of instances that the predicate `path/n` has in the knowledgebase.

```
path(N, ...) :- N >= 0.0, N < 0.2, ...
path(N, ...) :- N >= 0.2, N < 0.4, ...
path(N, ...) :- N >= 0.4, N < 0.6, ...
path(N, ...) :- N >= 0.6, N < 0.8, ...
path(N, ...) :- N >= 0.8, N <= 1.0, ...
```

With this embedding of ranges, we are making all the instances of `path/n` equally likely to be considered.  Whenever `path/n` is called in the RHS of a rule or production (right of `:-` or `-->`), it should be preceded by the generation of a random float between 0 and 1 which is passed as the first argument to `path/n`; e.g. `foo :- random(N), path(N, ...).`.

This would of course become cumbersome over time as the knowledge base increases in size, so you might want to write a compiler (like the DCG compiler) that generates the randomness threading for you.  Writing these sorts of compilers in Prolog is surprisingly not too much work thanks to predicates like `asserta` and `assertz`.

If you are using this "random derivation search" as a method to avoid infinite left recursion, know that a much nicer method might simply be to write the solution so that it uses breadth-first search rather than Prolog's intuitive depth-first.  This involved threading a `State` argument into all your predicates (worth a google: Prolog breadth-first).

*EDIT*:  Prolog is also higher-order logic (HOL), except in the strict left-derivation, first-predicate-first-considered way, which leads to problems with left recursion.  You could use the (HOL) features of Prolog to model a search approach that considers all predicates evenly (assuming the predicates are pure predicates, no arithmetic, etc.).  For example, store all the right hand sides as a list of predicates `[[p1, p1a1,...],[p2,p2a1,...]|_]`, randomize the list before evaluation, then evaluate the shuffled list of predicates iteratively by building up the predicate using the `=..` operator, i.e. `X =.. [p1, p1a1, p1a2], X.`  The `X` in this snippet is unified with `p1(p1a1,p1a2)`, and is then searched for satisfiability.