# Define bind without join for the list monad in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I understand the definition of `>>=` in term of `join`

```
xs >>= f = join (fmap f xs)
```

which also tells us that `fmap + join` yields `>>=`

I was wondering if for the `List` monad it's possible to define without `join`, as we do for example for `Maybe`:

```
>>= m f = case m of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just x  -> f x
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. The actual definition in `GHC/Base.hs` is in terms of the equivalent list comprehension:

```
instance Monad []  where
    xs >>= f             = [y | x <- xs, y <- f x]
```

Alternatively, you could try the following method of working it out from scratch from the type:

```
(>>=) :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
```

We need to handle two cases:

```
[] >>= f = ???
(x:xs) >>= f = ???
```

The first is easy.  We have no elements of type `a`, so we can't apply `f`.  The only thing we can do is return an empty list:

```
[] >>= f = []
```

For the second, `x` is a value of type `a`, so we can apply `f` giving us a value of `f x` of type `[b]`.  That's the beginning of our list, and we can concatenate it with the rest of the list generated by a recursive call:

```
(x:xs) >>= f = f x ++ (xs >>= f)
```

Comment: and that is exactly as it was given [in the Reasoned Schemer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10848902/849891)! (only, in Scheme; without ever mentioning the "M" word). They even had *two* different "binds" there.