# In Racket's mini-kanren libraries, where is condi?

Tags: racket, minikanren

The mini-kanren language features four conditional operators: `conda`, `conde`, `condi` and `condu` (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843563/conda-condi-conde-condu)). There are two mini-kanren libraries available for Racket that I am aware of (both described [here](https://www.monolune.com/using-racket-for-the-reasoned-schemer/)). Neither of them implements `condi`.

My impression (halfway through reading The Reasoned Schemer, which minikanren.org calls "The Book") is that `condi` is important: it is the only conditional that takes the "fair disjunction" by interleaving branches, so you don't get stuck infinite-looping in a branch that never terminates when some other does terminate.

EDIT: I may have managed to implement `condi` myself, [here](https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/the-reasoned-schemer-in-racket/blob/master/condi.rkt). In The Reasoned Schemer, `conde` differs from `condi` only in that the last two arguments to `mplus` are flipped in `mplusi`, so that's what I implemented. But it's not working any more fairly than `conde`, from what I can tell.

Comment: ["conde *is* condi now"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10850364/849891). if I understand that answer correctly, there is no more old `conde` behaviour. new `conde` behaves like the old `condi`, so there's no more need for a separate `condi` since `conde` is doing its job now.